Uniformization and constructive analytic continuation of Taylor-Maclaurin series
Context. In their paper, "Uniformization and Constructive Analytic Continuation of  Taylor Series", Costin and Dunne present a constructive method to greatly increase the accuracy of a Taylor-Maclaurin series expansion. They achieve this by solving the problem of global reconstruction of functions as accurately as possible, based on partial information in the form of a power series truncated at some point, and additional analyticity properties leading to a remarkable gain in series accuracy. Their method is based on the uniformization of Riemann surfaces.
From the paper:

Figure 1. The map $z = \psi\left(\omega\right)$ from the simply
connected Riemann surface $\Omega$ (here the universal cover of
$\mathbb {\hat C}  \setminus \{\pm i, \infty \})$ to the unit disk
$\mathbb D$, and its inverse $\omega = \phi\left(z\right)$
Definition 1. We denote by $\psi$ the conformal map of $\Omega$ onto
the unit disk $\mathbb D$, uniquely specified by the normalization
$\psi\left(0\right) = 0, \psi′\left(0\right) \gt 0$, and we write the
inverse map $\psi^{−1} = \phi$, the covering map of $\Omega$.

For a Taylor-Maclaurin series $P_n(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} p_k z^k$, they find that the optimal approximant is given by $\hat R_n = \left(P_n \circ \phi_n\right)_n \circ \psi$ where $\phi_n$ is the inverse map truncated at $n$ after a series expansion.
The paper focuses on constructing and using conformal and inverse maps for $\Omega \left( \mathbb {\hat C} \setminus \{\left(0 \right), 1, \infty \} \right)$. Some other conformal maps and their inverses are discussed in the Appendix, but none seem to apply to my case of interest.
Question. I am interested in a simpler case: a Taylor-Maclaurin series $P_n(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} p_k z^k$ holomorphic on $\mathbb {\hat C}$ for

$\operatorname{Re}(z) \ge 0$, i.e., the right side of the complex plane; or at least

$\operatorname{Re}(z) \in \left[0, a\right]$ for some $a \in \mathbb R^+$


The first conformal map to the unit disk that came to mind was
$$z = \psi \left ( \omega \right ) = {\omega - 1 \over \omega + 1}  $$
however, this map does not satisfy the $\psi\left(0\right) = 0$ normalization. As $z = \psi\left(0\right) = -1$ lies on the boundary of $\mathbb D$, the unit circle $\mathbb T = \partial \mathbb D$, my understanding is that it is not possible to further apply a conformal automorphism.
Any insight as to how to proceed would be appreciated.
